# Speed of water waves (deep water)

Tags: waves, surface-tension, dispersion

In papers said

> "In water,the dispersion relation of the waves (and therefore, the speed of the wave) depends on the wavenumber $k$, water density $ρ$ and depth $h$, surface tension $T$ and gravity $g$ through the relation."

but I don't understand the final equation source. How do we prove $c=ω/k$ is
equal to final equation?

$$c=\frac{w}{k}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{g}{k}+\frac{tk}{p}\right) \tanh kh}$$

ps.based from this papers https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352693034_Evaluating_shallow_water_waves_by_observing_Mach_cones_on_the_beach

Comment: I corrected a bad error in your transcription. The small surface tension and wavenumber limit used in the paper is adduced in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave#Physics_of_waves), and can be found in most good wave books, presumably the author's ref [7]. This site provides answers, not extensive tutorial lectures.

Comment: This link may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737237/2451

Comment: Hi NOVA C. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: this is equation 3.2.3 as derived by Phillips in https://archive.org/details/dynamicsofuppero0000phil/page/n9/mode/2up Ch 3, pp22-25, not difficult but long